# When using "re.search", how do I search for the second instance rather than the first?

Tags: python, regex

re.search looks for the first instance of something. In the following code, "\t" appears twice. Is there a way to make it skip forward to the second instance?

```
code = ['69.22\t82.62\t134.549\n']
list = []
text = code
m = re.search('\t(.+?)\n', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
    list.append(found)
```

result:

```
list = ['82.62\t134.549']
```

expected:

```
list = ['134.549']
```

Comment: and if there would be 4 tabs, which match is required?

Comment: Or put the pattern in twice, with a set excluding the pattern in between (`[^\t]+`); or use a non-greedy match in between, as you already do now.

Comment: @00 Non-greedy doesn't help. That shortens the match on the right, not the left.

Comment: There is only one solution for greater than the "second" tab. That is `^(?:[^\t]*\t){2}(.*?)\n`

Comment: @sln Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This modified version of your expression does return the desired output:

```
import re

code = '69.22\t82.62\t134.549\n'
print(re.findall(r'.*\t(.+?)\n', code))
```

#### Output

```
['134.549']
```

I'm though guessing that maybe you'd like to design an expression, somewhat similar to:

```
(?<=[\t])(.+?)(?=[\n])
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eTUWRB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one solution for greater than the "second" tab.
You can do it like this  :

`^(?:[^\t]*\t){2}(.*?)\n`

Explained

```
 ^                     # BOS
 (?:                   # Cluster
      [^\t]*                # Many not tab characters
      \t                    # A tab
 ){2}                  # End cluster, do 2 times
 ( .*? )               # (1), anything up to
 \n                    # first newline
```

Python code

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '69.22\t82.62\t134.549\n'
>>> m = re.search('^(?:[^\t]*\t){2}(.*?)\n', text)
>>> if m:
>>>     print( m.group(1) )
...
134.549
>>>
```